# Convert to reducing function using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Hey I've been trying to convert the below code to Java streams but can't seem to get it to work:

```
private Map<String, Object> process(List<Config> configs, Map<String, Object> seedConfig)
            throws IOException {

    var current = seedConfig;
    for (var config : configs) {
        var configProcessor = new ConfigProcessor(config.getType());
        current = configProcessor.processConfig(config, current);
    }
    return current;
}

// where config is a class defined as:
public class {

    public Map<String, Object> processConfig(Config config, Map<String, Object> seedMessage) {
        // do something there that builds on top of the seedMessage
    }
}
```

The goal of the code is to build to the final state of the config in the iterative steps and then return the final built config.

Comment: I don't think there _is_ an ideal streams conversion for that code.  I'd leave it as it is.

Comment: Why convert to streams anyway?  The Stream capability and other Java 8 enhancements are there to make your coding easier.  So why rewrite it if it already works?  And in general  Java's declarative programming API with its complex overhead tends not to be as efficient as imperative programming.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was just being curious, I agree streams would complicate a simple thing but just wanted to know how it could have been done (if at all possible)

Comment: @WJS I agree, but I thought the overhead wasn't as huge as compared to imperative alternative and it was only noticeable over larger iterations. Is that not the case?

Comment: @iam.Carrot Consider that the API is coded at some point in its hierarchy using imperative constructs and must handle a variety of situations. So the APi is like the middle man that adds cost but also takes care of simplifying the deal.  At least that is how I view it.

Comment: @iam.Carrot it’s the opposite. The larger the iteration, the more work will be done by the optimizer, to eliminate the overhead or, in same cases, even benefit from the Stream API. However, your operation is as much an iterative process as it can be. It’s hard to imagine any potential for optimizations.

Comment: @Holger thanks, that provides a lot of clarity.

Comment: @WJS I agree, this entire push for declarative paradigm has me in questions haha

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Map<String, Object> process(List<Config> configs, Map<String, Object> seedConfig) {
        return configs.stream()
                .reduce(seedConfig, (current, config) -> {
                    var configProcessor = new ConfigProcessor(config.getType());
                    return configProcessor.processConfig(config, current);
                }, (a, b) -> b);
    }
```